# Using Regular Expressions to split a string in Java

Tags: java, regex

I'm attempting to find the fields in a user defined string and create an array out of them. For example, if the user enters:

```
abc @{fieldOne} defg @{FieldTwo} 123 @{FieldThree} zyx
```

I want as a result:

```
fields[0] = "@{fieldOne}"
fields[1] = "@{fieldTwo}"
fields[2] = "@{FieldThree}"
```

I've got a regular expression to find the substrings: `/@{[a-zA-Z]*}/g` but I have been unsuccessful in using it in Java to break up the string. Here's what I've got at the moment, and tried variations of:

```
String displayString = "abc @{fieldOne} defg @{FieldTwo} 123 @{FieldThree} zyx";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("/@\\{[a-zA-Z]*\\}/g");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(displayString);
```

`matcher.matches()` is returning false - I'm guessing the formatting of my regexp is incorrect, but I haven't been able to figure out what it should be.

Thanks in advance for comments and answers!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No need for the forward slashes or `//g` modifier. Also, use double escapes.

```
String displayString = "abc @{fieldOne} defg @{FieldTwo} 123 @{FieldThree} zyx";

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("@\\{[a-zA-Z]*\\}");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(displayString);
while ( matcher.find() ){
    System.out.println(matcher.group(0));
}
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you! (I did have double slashes, just not in my original SO post). My main problem was using `matcher.matches()` as that wasn't doing what I expected.. so no matter what I had as the regex that was returning false. Thanks for posting the output of the matches!